# Import module located in sub folder in Goland IDE

Tags: go, go-modules, goland

How can I get Goland to lint my `go.mod` correctly and not report "missing dependency" errors for a module I am maintaining in a sub directory of my main project?

I'm trying to follow the pattern in [hashicorp's vault project](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault) where I maintain an `api` module in a sub folder (that can be imported by others without dragging in all deps used by my main project.) Just like in vault, I reference the api module by url in my main project's `go.mod` and override it with a `replace` pointing to the relative path location.

```
module github.com/hashicorp/vault

go 1.16

replace github.com/hashicorp/vault/api => ./api

// ...
require (
    // ...
    github.com/hashicorp/vault/api v1.0.5-0.20210210214158-405eced08457
    // ...
)
```

All this works as expected from a build perspective (and dependency resolution within the source code), however Goland is highlighting both the import statement and the replace statement in my main project's `go.mod` in red (the error is "missing dependency"). The red lightbulb suggests I "Sync Dependencies" which i have tried, but after a "Finished Successfully" message, the error remains.

I am using Goland 2020.3.5 and go 1.16.3. My project is outside of my GOPATH and I have go modules enabled in the Goland settings menu.

Just to reiterate, everything builds correctly, however the linting for my go.mod acts like there is a missing dependency error.

Comment: Does update to the 2021.1.3 version help?

Comment: doh! upgrading did the trick - _why wasn't that the first thing I tried?_
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version of Goland (2021.1.3) solved the issue.
Thanks @s0xzwasd !